# JAX-WS marshalling Error. SomeClassV1R5 cannot be converted into the destination type of SomeClass

Tags: java, soap, websphere, jax-ws, apache-axis

We have migrated from JAX-RPC to JAX-WS services with Websphere(8.5.5 service pack 13) and default Axis2 implementation. All services are running fine but 1 client getting strange error for the same operations which are working fine for others. We enabled SOAP logs and tried same request with SOAPUI which worked fine. Below is the stack trace. The `GetTransactionsV1R8RequestType` is not extending `GetTransactionsRequestType`.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: An internal error occurred during JAX-WS marshalling. An object of type com.kk.v1.GetTransactionsV1R8RequestType cannot be converted into the destination type of com.kk.v1.GetTransactionsRequestType
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createRequestSignatureArgs(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:482)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.demarshalRequest(DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.createRequestParameters(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:322)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)
```

Answer (score 0):

After much struggle I am able find the root cause. In this scenario client calling our API using raw `SOAP XML` over `HTTP`. XML has request name as `GetTransactionsV1R8RequestType` and request is getting validated against XSD/schema successfully. In `HTTP` connection, client setting `SOAPAction` property with value as 'getTransactions' which is initial version of API. The request name is `XML` is `getTransactionsV1R8RequestType` with which expected SOAP operation is 'getTransactionsV1R8'.

Setting proper `SOAPAction` value resolved the problem.

Another observation with this is `GetTransactionsV1R8RequestType` is not extending `GetTransactionsRequestType` but was extending `GetTransactionsV1R5RequestType` and if we set `SOAPAction` value as '`getTransactionsV1R5`' with `SOAP XML` `GetTransactionsV1R8RequestType`, it's get getting successfully called with operation '`getTransactionsV1R5`' as `GetTransactionsV1R8RequestType` can be cast to `GetTransactionsV1R5RequestType`.